# Wildcards Generics - непонятная ошибка

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    List<?> intList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList2.add(new Integer(10)); //компилятор выдает ошибку
    intList2.add(new Float(10.0f)); //тут компилятор тоже выдает ошибку
}
```

Интересно знать, а в чем причина ошибок? Если вторая ошибка хоть немного понятна, то первая вообще не понятна.

Доп. инфо: Я знаю, что

```
        1) "subtyping does not work for generic type parameters: you cannot
            assign a derived generic type parameter to a base type parameter." 

        2) "you can use a wildcard to indicate that it can match for any
            type. With List<?>, you mean that it is a List of any type—in 
            other words, you can say it is a “list of unknowns!”"
```

если что.

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

ошибка следующая

```
Warning:(30, 22) java: Integer(int) in java.lang.Integer has been deprecated
Error:(30, 17) java: no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Integer)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?)

Warning:(31, 22) java: Float(float) in java.lang.Float has been deprecated
Error:(31, 17) java: no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Float)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#2 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Float cannot be converted to capture#2 of ?)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#2 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Float cannot be converted to capture#2 of ?)
```

Comment: *компилятор выдает ошибку* - какую? приведите [mcve]

Comment: @VTT вопрос обновил, можете посмотреть

Comment: Нельзя в коллекцию c unbounded wildcard добавлять элементы. Да и извлекать тоже нельзя.

Comment: прочитал документацию Oracle " When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter. For example, List.size or List.clear. In fact, Class<?> is so often used because most of the methods in Class<T> do not depend on T."  по этой ссылке https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то если метод не имеет воздействие на тип T в Class<T> то при Class<?> проблем не будет.

Comment: Поэкспериментировал. Пожалуй все вопросы нейтрализованы. Спасибо @SergeyGornostaev.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете **безопасно** добавить в коллекцию параметризованную метасимвольным аргументом ? только null.Остальные добавления являются не безопасными.
В вашем случае , вы пытаетесь добавить инстанс класса Integer в коллекцию с не известным типом.Эта коллекция может содержать любой тип данных - String , Number , Integer , Float и т.д.

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(new Integer(33));
// Это добавление безопасно только для коллекции типизированной типом Number & Integer.
list.add(new Double(33.4d));
// Безопасно только для коллекции типа Number & Double
list.add(null);
// Безопасно для коллекции любого типа.
```

Вот какую проблему решает такое поведение обобщений.

```
Integer[] ints = new Integer[10];
Object[] objs = ints;
objs[0] = "Hello,World!"; // Exception ArrayStoreException will be thrown
objs[1] = 23.34;//The same exception
```

Хотя в java массивы коварианты - означает , что массив типа Integer является и массивом типа Object , это грозит исключением выше.В массив типа Integer не может быть добавлена строка или числа Double.Так само и с обобщениями.

Comment: Тогда завершающий вопрос.  А что насчет выражения list.add(new Object()); ? Почему выдается ошибка? add(capture<?>) in List cannot be applied to (java.lag.Object)

Comment: Вопрос возник на основе того, что надо чтобы было так  "Безопасно для коллекции любого типа."

Comment: У нас List может быть параметризованный типом Number . В тип Number мы не можем добавить Object.Безопасно в List<?> можно добавить только null.

Comment: Пардон, но в List<?> intList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); вместо "?" не может быть "Number", другое дело, если List<Number> intList2 = new ArrayList<>(); так можно но это уже мы отклонимся от рамок моего вопроса.

Comment: Это вы сказали , что вместо ? не может быть Number ибо вы видите , чему присвоена ссылка(в данном случае ArrayList<Integer>).Компилятор считает , что List типизирован любым обьектом(неизвестным ему) и запрещает добавлять любой элемент кроме значения null.

Answer (score 0):

Дженерики и вайлдкарды созданы не для вывода типов (автоматического определения типа в месте использования), а для проверки совместимости типов в момент компиляции. Компилятор не пытается вывести тип, он просто читает как есть и проверяет совместимость типов. `<?>`- обозначает какой-то неизвестный тип, `Collection<?>` - коллекция объектов неизвестного типа.

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(new Integer(33));
```

Как читает это компилятор:

1. Создать `ArrayList` для хранения объектов `Integer`.
2. Создать ссылку на реализацию `List` хранящую объекты неизвестного типа.
3. Присвоить к `List` содержащую объекты неизвестного типа ссылку на `ArrayList` содержащий объекты с типом `Integer`. Ошибки нет, ведь мы можем ссылаться на что-то конкретное как на непонятно что.
4. Добавить `Integer` в реализацию `List` содержащую объекты неизвестного типа.
   Ошибка: нельзя передать `Integer` в `List` объектов неизвестного типа , типы могут оказаться не совместимы, ведь `List<?>` может ссылаться на `ArrayList<String>`.